# How to count number of matchings?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Suppose we have a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $(A,B)$ such that $A=\{a_{1},...a_{n}\}$ and $B=\{b_{1},...,b_{n},b_{n+1} \}$ and the vertex $a_{k}$ is adjacent to $b_{1}, b_{2} , .... , b_{k+1}$ for $k=1,2,..n$

Then it can be shown that there exist exactly $2^{n}$ matching's in G that cover A. Why?

I tried to do it by induction, also I know about Halls thereom but I am not sure I will need it.

The base case is clear because we have exactly two matching, each consists of a single edge.

Next I suppose that it is true for $n-1$ and want to show this implies it is true for n.  But that is where I am stuck.

I know that going from $n-1$ to n will cause the addition of two new vertices, one in A and one in B.

I thought maybe we could partition the matching's for n as $M1,M2,...M(2^{k-1})$

but then I am not sure how to proceed.

Maybe induction isn't even the correct way? If not maybe I could use thereoms for bipartite graphs such as the fact that the maximum matching number is equal to the minimum vertex number?

Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think induction on the number of nodes in the graph is the clearest way to go. Instead, induct *on the nodes* like this (although, in the end, it's *exactly* the same thing): A matching that covers $A$ must specifically cover $a_1$. How many choices of edges do you have to do that? Once you've made that choice, how many choices do you have to pick an edge that covers $a_2$? Now keep going, and you'll get your answer.

Comment: oh, that's nice.

Comment: Thank you , but can you please help me to understand what you mean by, 
"how many choices do you have " in that context? Do you mean choices for which edge?  A matching that covers A must cover $a_{1}$, so we have two choices of an edge. Now it must cover a_{2}, which has 3 edges, one of which will have an end being a vertex of the ones before it. Is that correct interpretation?

Comment: @PersonaA Yes. One of the edges leading up to $a_2$ will be useless because the $b_i$ at the other end is already part of the matching. Therefore you once again have two choices for which edge you want to have in your matching. Then, for $a_3$, there are four edges, but two of them are illegal to put in our matching, so we only have two to chose from. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

you want the bijections of $\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$ such that $f(k)\leq k+1$ for all $k$.

as you guessed we can count them by indution.

If we have $f(n)=n$ then there are clearly $2^{n-1}$ such function by the iduction hypothesis.. If we do not have $f(n)=n$ then we must clearly have $f(n-1)=n$ and every "good" bijection of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ gives us a good function $f$ such that $f(n)\neq n$ by letting $f(k)=g(k)$ for $k<n$ , letting $f(n-1)=g(n)$ and letting $f(n)=g(n-1)$. this assignment is bijective.

So there are $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$ such functions.